# How to use sqoop2 to import mysql table which id filed is string type?

Tags: sqoop2

I try to use sqoop2 (1.99.7) to import mysql table. When creating the sqoop job, the default partition column is id. But in the mysql table, the id is a char[36] field. And I don't have any numeric field in this table.

The imported table DDL is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE `project` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_last_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_3k75vvu7mevyvvb5may5lj8k7` (`name`),
  KEY `FKklsjfrbvub6jy50shboiiqjsm` (`create_user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKklsjfrbvub6jy50shboiiqjsm` FOREIGN KEY (`create_user_id`)     REFERENCES `platform_user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The job will take the 'id' field as the default partition column.

The sqoop job is as follow：

```
1 job(s) to show: 
Job with name job1 (Enabled: true, Created by liupeng at 2/2/18 12:57 PM, Updated by xxxx at 2/2/18 2:48 PM)
  Throttling resources
    Extractors: 
    Loaders: 
  Classpath configuration
    Extra mapper jars: 
From link: jdbclink
  Database source
    Schema name: sailor
    Table name: project
    SQL statement: 
    Column names: 
    Partition column: 
    Partition column nullable: 
    Boundary query: 
  Incremental read
    Check column: 
    Last value: 
To link: hdfslink
  Target configuration
    Override null value: 
    Null value: 
    File format: TEXT_FILE
    Compression codec: NONE
    Custom codec: 
    Output directory: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/xxxx
    Append mode:
```

The job error is as follow:

```
sqoop:000> start job -n job1
2018-02-02 14:48:52 CST: FAILURE_ON_SUBMIT 
Exception: org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException: CORE_0000:An unknown error has occurred
Stack trace: org.apache.sqoop.common.SqoopException: CORE_0000:An unknown error has occurred
at org.apache.sqoop.utils.ClassUtils.executeWithClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:286)
at org.apache.sqoop.job.mr.SqoopInputFormat.getSplits(SqoopInputFormat.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:313)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1570)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1567)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1962)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1567)
at org.apache.sqoop.submission.mapreduce.MapreduceSubmissionEngine.submitToCluster(MapreduceSubmissionEngine.java:279)
at org.apache.sqoop.submission.mapreduce.MapreduceSubmissionEngine.submit(MapreduceSubmissionEngine.java:260)
at org.apache.sqoop.driver.JobManager.start(JobManager.java:329)
at org.apache.sqoop.handler.JobRequestHandler.startJob(JobRequestHandler.java:353)
at org.apache.sqoop.handler.JobRequestHandler.handleEvent(JobRequestHandler.java:114)
at org.apache.sqoop.server.v1.JobServlet.handlePutRequest(JobServlet.java:84)
at org.apache.sqoop.server.SqoopProtocolServlet.doPut(SqoopProtocolServlet.java:81)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:644)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:304)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:592)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal
at org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcPartitioner.constructTextConditions(GenericJdbcPartitioner.java:490)
at org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcPartitioner.partitionTextColumn(GenericJdbcPartitioner.java:221)
at org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcPartitioner.getPartitions(GenericJdbcPartitioner.java:123)
at org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcPartitioner.getPartitions(GenericJdbcPartitioner.java:38)
at org.apache.sqoop.job.mr.SqoopInputFormat.getSplitsInternal(SqoopInputFormat.java:97)
at org.apache.sqoop.job.mr.SqoopInputFormat.access$000(SqoopInputFormat.java:49)
at org.apache.sqoop.job.mr.SqoopInputFormat$1.call(SqoopInputFormat.java:76)
at org.apache.sqoop.job.mr.SqoopInputFormat$1.call(SqoopInputFormat.java:73)
at org.apache.sqoop.utils.ClassUtils.executeWithClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:281)
... 38 more
```

How can I achieve this importing?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not providing enough information, add your sqoop job and show us the error you are getting. if possible add the describe on MySQL table hiding the column names.

Comment: just add more information according to @roh's suggestion.